# Fetchall() is excluding one row which is stored in fetchrow()

Tags: python, fetchall

I am trying to create a code where i would get all the rows from the existing table if the condition matches otherwise return "Record is not there". Below fetchall() excludes one row which is sitting in fetchone() function. As i am new to this, i am not sure what is going wrong.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

result=cursor.execute("SELECT * from Documents where documentID like '1167%')

row= cursor.fetchone()

if row is None:     
     print('Record is not there')

else:

     row=cursor.fetchall()
     print(row)
```

Comment: What language is this?  What DBMS?

Comment: i am using python in which i have created the connection with DBMS

Comment: The second line is missing a `"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Note that this is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site about all programming related problems. Thus, in the future please [edit] your posts to contain the tag of the language you are using. That way, Python users (or in the relevant language) can find your post much more easily.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you reassemble your rows in a list using the * :

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("SELECT * from Documents where documentID like '1167%'")
row = cursor.fetchone()

if row is None:     
     print('Record is not there')
else:
     other_rows=cursor.fetchall()
     rows = [row, *other_rows]
     print(rows)
```

Comment: This misses a very important point: the typo on the second line. Please read [answer], when answering always strive to solve all problems in a question and at the very least make sure that a piece of code you post actually works.